# TrueStudio "Could not determine GDB version command" error

Tags: eclipse, gdb, embedded-system

I am working with TrueStudio. I face with this error when click Debug button. https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhN6q.jpg  How can I fix this problem? Before this in the build step I saw another warning as you can see below;

```
Cannot run program "arm-atollic-eabi-objcopy.exe": Unknown reason

Error: Program "arm-atollic-eabi-objcopy.exe" not found in PATH
PATH=[/opt/Atollic_TrueSTUDIO_for_STM32_x86_64_9.3.0/ARMTools/bin:/opt/Atollic_TrueSTUDIO_for_STM32_x86_64_9.3.0/Tools:/home/asus/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin]
```

However I read a post which is mentioned that it is not a problem for Linux.
Beside that, I am using Ubuntu Dingo Disco.

Thanks.

Comment: So *is* the program in the path, or isn't it?

Comment: Sorry which path?

Comment: Your Ubuntu session has a variable $PATH, which is a collection of known and trusted directories. Programs in those directories do not need to be specified with their full path name to be executed. The actual PATH is given in the error message that you show. Your program `arm-atollic-eabi-objcopy.exe` was not found, however. So either the program is not there, or the PATH is missing something.

Comment: I migrate this example from Windows enviroment to Linux. Maybe this is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found solution. So for solve problem you should install libncurses5 library. Command is `sudo apt install libncurses5` .

Thanks for helps.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks :)

Comment: good to hear it worked mate :)